# Java - Concise if statement

Tags: java, if-statement

I really don't know what should be the title of this question, spent 10 minutes but this is the best I came up with.

The real question is very basic and I think I know the answer. But still, like the operator `condition ? true-statement : false-statement`, is there any shortcut of this kind of `if statement`?

```
    if(intA == -1 || intB == -1 || intC == -1 || intD == -1 || intE == -1)
```

*Suggestion: Something like this could be added in Java:*

```
    if((intA || intB || intC || intD || intE) == -1)
```

Comment: No, there isn't - and Stack Overflow isn't really an appropriate place for language feature requests. Do you really need 5 separate variables here? If you had a collection instead, there are other alternatives...

Comment: @JonSkeet: No its just a question, like that `? :` operator exists, so I thought there might be something for this kind of situation too.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I have another question, not related to this topic. How can I ask you that? Should I mention its [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31640967/1708390) here?

Comment: You don't ask *me* that - you ask it as a separate Stack Overflow question, assuming it *is* a separate question. If it's a request for clarification on an answer, then a comment would be appropriate.

Comment: Yes it was a request for clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.. There isn't.  These are different variables with different values.

Suggestion: you can consider the all these variable necessary or not. If all these variables necessary there will be no way to simplify.

Comment: well on different variables Java could throw some `Runtime Exception`, like "Couldn't cast".

Comment: @BugsHappen you got my point wrong.. I am telling "different variable" means those are not referring the same variable and could not simplify.

Comment: Sorry, couldn't understand your suggestion. Please explain

Comment: @BugsHappen I mean some times we use variable without thinking... some time we can reuse same variable. Sometime we can reduce the scope of the variable..

Comment: @BugsHappen I have edited my answer. Now it may clear to you

Answer (score 1):

Afaik, there is no *real* shortcut syntax for this. Probably, you could do some tricks with logical and/or to achieve this, but I would not recommend to do so as it would be harder to read:

```
if (((intA | intB | intC) & -1) == -1)
```

You could still add those ints to an collection, and check if -1 is contained in that collection.

**Fun fact:** In Python, there is syntactic sugar for comparing a variable with 2 values; you can write *2 < a < 3*, which would not be possible in Java. But personally, I do not know a language where syntactic sugar for what you are asking for exists.

Answer (score 1):

You should use lists for this purpose.
For ex. 
You can implement function

```
findFirstEquals(List, Int)
```

which iterate through the list, search for first element that equals to second parameter and returns true if found.

In this case your if would be like following

```
intList = ArrayList<Int>()
// put 5, 6, 7,8 etc...
if findFirstEquals(intList, -1) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Switch()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) statement to make it more easy like below

```
 public void myMethod(int intValue)
 {
       switch (intValue) {
                 case -1:  //Your logic here ;
                           break;
                 case 1 : //Another condition
                           break;
                 default: //Default behaviour;
                           break;
       }              
 }
```

Call method `myMethod(yourValue)` and passed your value to it.

Passed your integer value to switch it will handle it as per value you have passed.

May this will help you.